# Read portion of bytes from stdin in COBOL

Tags: cobol, acucobol-gt

I'm trying to get a portion of bytes from stdin using ACUCOBOL-GT. Because the data could be of any length, specifying a `variable PIC X(n)` and then using `ACCEPT variable` won't work, since the **whole line** is read, and the input line is truncated to the length of `variable`.

For example, if the stdin contains this:

```
Some line exceeding 10 caracters↵
and then another line↵
and at last a third line.
```

and I have this code:

```cobol
working-storage division.

 77 someLine pic X(10).

procedure division.

    perform 3 times
        accept someLine;
        display someLine;
    end-perform;
```

then the result is only

```
Some line ↵
and then a↵
and at las
```

Apparently, each `ACCEPT` reads until a newline is found, and then moves the line into the specified variable, possibly truncating a part of the line.

Now I want to read only a portion of stdin, so no bytes get discarded. I tried to assign a file descriptor to the stdin using `SYSIN`, as recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938760/read-stdin-sysin-in-cobol):

```cobol
    select sysin
        assign to keyboard
        organization binary sequential.

data division.
file section.

fd sysin.
01 inputByte pic X.

procedure division.

    open input sysin
    perform 3 times
        accept inputByte from sysin
        display inputByte
    end-perform
    close sysin.
```

But it somehow gives an File error 35 (file not found). Seems like ACUCOBOL-GT

> [does not support](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/topic/com.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.extendACUSuite/BKTRTRICBLS004.html) the direct assignment to the user's screen or keyboard.

Can I somehow force `ACCEPT` to read a specified number of bytes instead of scanning for a newline? Or can I somehow use `READ SYSIN NEXT`?

Comment: Can you provide some data which reflects what you want to do? Generally, a plain ACCEPT will consume an input record and you will not see data that does not "fit" into what you have ACCEPTed into. There are often Extensions to ACCEPT and DISPLAY, and I think there are many in AcuCOBOL. Do you want keyboard input, or "sysin" input that happens to have been typed at some point in the past (by the time the program runs)

Comment: @BillWoodger For example, POST data passed in through CGI or a program that pipes its output to the COBOL program. I do no require keystrokes per se, but bytes from the standard input.

Comment: So you are dealing with potentially different inputs which you want to deal with in different ways depending on the first part of the text? The "easy" way is to define something that is the maximum size that you could possibly receive, so you get all the data, and then define for the first portion to test. Someone with AcuCOBOL experience my have other ideas.

Comment: @BillWoodger The contents of the stdin don't have a predefined structure. In contrast, it could have **any length**, and it's possibly larger than the maximum `PICTURE` size, if any.

Comment: I'd suggest to check out `C$GETCGI`[1] or try to get the pointer to stdin, assign its address to a `PIC X(1)` in `LINKAGE ITEM` to it and use a perform to get the data until EOF.

[1]:http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/topic/com.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.extendACUSuite/BKPPPPLIBRS055.html?cp=5_0_1_4_8_0_20
[2]:http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/topic/com.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.extendACUSuite/BKPPPPLIBRS071.html?cp=5_0_1_4_8_0_36

Comment: Using `C$GETCGI` won't work, unfortunately, because it only allows to copy its value to a fixed-size working-storage variable. Using `C$MEMCPY` could be an option, if I only knew how to retrieve that pointer...